# C++ Weird behaviour of probably double included header files

Tags: c++

This is my code and it is compiling:

```
#include "Config.h"
#include "Banner.h"
#include "AuthServer.h"
#include "Server/Service/Connection/ConnectMethod.h"


using namespace std;
using namespace Vibranium;

AuthServer::AuthServer(std::string ip, std::string port) : Server(ip, port){}

void AuthServer::HandleRpcs() {
    // Spawn a new CallData instance to serve new clients.
    new ConnectMethod(&connectionService_, cq_.get());
    void* tag;  // uniquely identifies a request.
    bool ok;
    while (true) {
        GPR_ASSERT(cq_->Next(&tag, &ok));
        GPR_ASSERT(ok);
        static_cast<ServiceMethod*>(tag)->Proceed();
    }
}

void AuthServer::RegisterServices(ServerBuilder &serverBuilder) {
    serverBuilder.RegisterService(&connectionService_);
}

int main() {
    //Don't mind Logger::FatalError it's just for coloring!
    Banner::Show(Logger::Error,"AuthServer");
    Config config("AuthServer");
    std::string defaultIp = "127.0.0.1";
    std::string defaultPort = "8080";


    try
    {
        AuthServer authServer(defaultIp, defaultPort);
        authServer.Run();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However if I add `#include "Implementation/LoginDatabase.h"` after `#include "AuthServer.h""` it compiles, if I add it before `#include "AuthServer.h"` I get the following strange error check it out here as it is long -> [Click Here!](https://gist.github.com/e0d31b43bca6ca65234444b44db4175a)

I'll provide the contents of the header files in GitHub Gists so I make the question more readable. Hope you don't mind that.

Here is contents of [Config.h](https://gist.github.com/Armmegon/677f8fd48c3c142bf5a135a49062f693) [LoginDatabase.h](https://gist.github.com/Armmegon/64b4a7118f01ab22851570b4f8ddc9af) [MySQlConnection.h](https://gist.github.com/Armmegon/95fab4cd49da4ca15fa7e5880d69ac52) [Banner.h](https://gist.github.com/366fcb9a7693ca1eb3b443c00c11b274) [AuthServer.h](https://gist.github.com/32d5db3501bbb2319b21baede137e3f4) [ConnectMethod.h](https://gist.github.com/dbd4e101a25a2b01bfcd755e49efb759)

By my understanding most likely I have somewhere double included header file or my header guards are not working?

Where is my mistake and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure there's no `#define INTERNAL` anywhere?

Comment: None in the whole project files @Yksisarvinen

Comment: @Yksisarvinen please take a look at the updated question `if I add #include "Implementation/LoginDatabase.h" after #include "AuthServer.h"" it compiles, if I add it before #include "AuthServer.h"`

Comment: So `AuthServer.h` contains something that `LoginDatabase.h` needs? Perhaps `LoginDatabase.h` should include `AuthServer.h`?

Comment: There are other include files in play that you don’t provide. One of those may have `#define INTERNAL`

Comment: Probably unrelated but really bad: You have `using namespace std;` in the global namespace in `Config.h`. That's not going to help.

Comment: Include the relevant code in the question itself, not in the links. Me e.g. I cannot open them because of my company policies.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I saw it too and removed it.

Comment: @KhouriGiordano I am searching whole project files for `#define INTERNAL` and there is nothing found.

Comment: I like the comment in the file I just looked at: "_If you are not employee with granted rights to read/write code for Vibranium Core please close this file immediately._" - Done :-)

Comment: Btw, `INTERNAL` isn't defined in one of _your_ project's files. It's defined in the [gRPC](https://github.com/grpc/grpc) library. Your file `Vibranium-Core/Source/Common/Server/Server.h` includes `grpcpp/grpcpp.h`  which indirectly includes `grpcpp/impl/codegen/status_code_enum.h` which contains the definition.

Comment: @TedLyngmo how can than I overcome this ?

Comment: It's hard to say without having access to the source. There are a lot of files included that you have not shared (which I'm sure you shouldn't share either because of the note I found). It looks like an unbalanced `{` and `}` pair - but then it shouldn't compile if you include it in a different order. I would definitely remove _all_ `using namespace <anything>;` from the global scope in your header files. Not even `using namespace Vibranium;` since it forces that upon all users of the header files.